# How to edit text style with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a button create new entries in a list that display similar to this:

"#1 new Click Me"

Except I want to make "Click Me" to show up as yellow text in a black box, and then I want to make the black box disappear and the text turn brown on mouseover. I've been able to make the list appear, but don't know how to edit the style of the text to make it appear the way I want to. The most code I think I need to give for this is this:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
var liBody = document.createTextNode("#"+numOfNewCMs+
     " new " + newClickMe);
li.appendChild(liBody);
```

And then I insert li into the list.

I figure I should make newClickMe a variable and edit that and then put it next to the rest of the text in the liBody variable, and I figure the HTML span element is the best way to do that, except I don't even know quite what the span element really does. How do I go about editing the style of that particular string? I can't get around to figuring out how (if I even can) make the text turn brown on mouseover until I do so.

Answer (score 0):

Never met CreateTextNode, but i guess`liBody.style.fontSize="12px"`should help. And other properties such as 'fontWeight,color,fontStyle...'

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements have a `style` property that can be used to apply CSS styles to them.

For example:

```
var newClickMe = document.createElement("span");
newClickMe.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
newClickMe.style.color = "#FFFF00";
newClickMe.innerText = "Click Me";

var li = document.createElement("li");
var liText = document.createTextNode("#"+numOfNewCMs+
     " new ");

li.appendChild(liText);
li.appendChild(newClickMe);
```

Will make the list item have a black background with yellow text.

For more details on the style property, MDN has a great section on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

And here is a reference page to translate CSS properties into their JavaScript equivalent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: Hey thanks! I assume if I make newClickMe a separate variable and then add it to the rest of liBody, it will make only the "Click Me" part of the string styled that way, am I correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct, if you make newClickMe its own element, like a `span` or something, you'll be able to apply styles specifically to it.

Comment: Hmm @NickCoad I tried this 

 ` var x = document.createElement("span");
  var newClickMe = document.createTextNode("Click Me");
  x.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  x.style.color = "FFFF00";
  var liBody = document.createTextNode("#"+numOfNewCMs+
  " new " + x ); `

And it printed

 #1 new [object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: Ugh sorry about that last comment, I tried to make it appear properly like code

Comment: newClickMe is now a HTML node, so you need to create the liBody and then append newClickMe to it, rather than treating it as text (`liBody.appendChild(newClickMe)`). I also noticed you are using `x.style` instead of `newClickMe.style`.

Comment: @Giverbud I've edited the answer to show the scenario you've described.

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained that. 

The web console told me newClickMe.style is undefined, so I tried to make a span element called x to append newClickMe to and then add that in the liBody variable.

Comment: you are a god amongst men. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the styles to change on mouseOver. I just changed the styles using css' :hover. Is this what you had in mind?

```js
var numOfNewCMs=1;
function generateLi(){
var li = document.createElement("li");
var liBody = document.createTextNode("#"+numOfNewCMs+
     " new ");
var sp = document.createElement("span");
var spBody = document.createTextNode("Click Me");
sp.setAttribute("id", "sp"+numOfNewCMs);
sp.setAttribute("onmouseover", "highlight("+numOfNewCMs+")");
sp.setAttribute("onmouseout", "highlight2("+numOfNewCMs+")");
sp.style.backgroundColor='black';
sp.style.color='yellow';
sp.appendChild(spBody);
li.appendChild(liBody);
li.appendChild(sp);
lis.appendChild(li);
numOfNewCMs++;
}

function highlight(id){
var element= document.getElementById('sp'+id);
element.style.backgroundColor='white';
element.style.color='brown';

}

function highlight2(id){
var element= document.getElementById('sp'+id);
element.style.backgroundColor='black';
element.style.color='yellow';

}
```

```css
li{
margin-bottom:20px;
}

li > span{
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}


li:hover > span{
color:brown;
background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateLi()">Click me</button>
<div id="lis" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: I can't use CSS because I'm doing all this from a separate .js file, do you know of any way to do that in javascript alone?

Comment: sure it can be done. check out my edited code above.